# nvd3 shows 0 values in tooltip on line chart for null values

Tags: nvd3.js

When I show tooltip from the section of values it shows all values including 0 values that don't appear on the graph.  Is there a way to remove these?

Comment: can you create a fiddle or plnkr?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/74gmx54n/1/

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late response.

I just ran into the same problem than you and I have a fix for you in that case.

In nv.d3.js, in the contentGenerator variable, you will find thoses lines:

```
trowEnter.append("td")
    .classed("value",true)
    .html(function(p,i) {return valueFormatter(p.value,i)});
```

Change this paragraph for this:

```
trowEnter.append("td")
              .classed("value",true)
              .html(function(p,i) {
               if (p.value === null) {this.parentNode.style.display = "none";}
               return valueFormatter(p.value,i) 
            });
```

It might not be the best way to do it, but it works for me when you pass null value in your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want 0 appear in the graph, you should remove it from dataset:

[option1](http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/pfjfkfug/1/)

If you want 0 appear in the graph, you could replace null with 0 in the dataset:

```
[1418757047000, null] -> [1418757047000, 0]
```

[option2](http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/pfjfkfug/)

I prefer option2, is it that you wanted?

Comment: I might not have been as clear as I wanted, but I want the values to not appear on the graph and when there is no value in a location, I want the hover to not have them showing.

Comment: option1 is like what you said? do not show on the graph

Comment: Well, the real problem lies, that when I highlight a date/time in the graph it would show only the values for that time/date or column if you will.  And any value that isn't shown on the graph would be hidden from the hover tooltip.  So in my example, the first column would only show `product1` and `product3`.  Meanwhile column two would only show `product1` and `product2`.  The reasoning is, when I use it in production, it can have upwards of 60+ products listed.  When some are valued, at 0 and display in the tooltip it can be hard to make sense of it.